# Period came again

Tags: salat, women, sawm

Suppose a girl's period ended on 3 may and after 3 or 4 days the blood came again and went after 3 hours and she is fasting so is her fast broken and what about her salah?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you’ve experienced is most likely spotting. In that case your fasts and prayers would be valid, but make sure to do wudu before each salat if it happens again. Allah knows best.

https://youtu.be/cMPTyCc7wxc